# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I use the following command:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

And the error message is:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is mysql daemon running? Have yot got a firewall? Can you telnet to mysql the default port is 306 so - telnet localhost 3306

Comment: the mysql daemon is running. I'm sure.

Comment: Is it just me or if you're connecting to the local mysql server you don't need to specify the host e.g. mysql -u root -p should work?

Comment: just to make sure, you are trying to connect to the db server locally?

Comment: I fresh installed mysql on ubuntu-12.04.2. The Version is 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2, its default config does not contain 'skip-networking'. So you would not encounter the error with this version.

Comment: You might want to confirm that mysqld is running on the IP:port you're thinking of by running  netstat -an | grep 3306

Comment: Why should tag "mysql-error-2003" exist?

Answer (score 250):

If you are using Ubuntu, you have to use the following steps to avoid this error (if there is no replication enabled):

1. run the command `vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. comment `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` using the # symbol
3. restart your MySQL server once.

In Step 1, if you cannot find `bind-address` in the `my.cnf` file, look for it in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file.

**Update in case of MySQL replication enabled**

Try to connect MySQL server on the IP address for which MySQL server is bound in file *my.cnf* instead of *localhost* or *127.0.0.1*.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I had been trying to figure this out for a long time!  I commented out that line, saved the file, and then ran `service mysql restart`.  And now it works!

Comment: In my case, I had the server's address instead of 127.0.0.1 for bind-address. If this is the case for you, you will need to comment that out as well.

Comment: There is no `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: @developer, i found mine here: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: I changed the bind-address = <main server ip>, but can't restart mysql.

Comment: I'm late to the party.
This did indeed help with the described issue (thanks for that), however it would be great if you could add a bit more explanatory text to your answer what exactly the issue is/ and how this fix helps.

Thanks again

Comment: If your flavour of Debian is running MariaDB -- who knows, you may find the bind address within the /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d directory; you may also locate file that bears the bind address by running this command within /etc/mysql/ :  grep -r "bind\-address" .

Comment: I am using `windows 7` , what should i do?

Comment: @justin, you saved my day. thanks. it works. though I had to restart mysql after this. But it worked. thanks.

Comment: This solved my issue too. To verify that you need the change, run `netstat -nat | grep:3306` to verify port 3306 is bound to 127.0.0.1 in the 4th column. After the instruction above, run the command again and the local address should be updated to `:::3306`. Thanks!

Comment: for my case, I had to bind 0.0.0.0

Comment: @JustinVincent - Thank you! Another update for you. I'm using Debian 10 (on a DigitalOcean server) and it's here: `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`.

Comment: Using Ubuntu and I found it in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` as well

Answer (score 19):

Try *localhost* instead of *127.0.0.1* to connect or in your `connection-config`. It worked for me on a [Debian 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_6.0_(Squeeze)) (Squeeze) Server.

Comment: FYI if you specify localhost, that tells Mysql to connect via the unix socket (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock on ubuntu) rather than over a TCP socket.

Answer (score 10):

In my case (remote connection), it helped turning off the firewall on the server:

```
service iptables stop
```

Comment: @ram Probably you are using some other firewall. Or your problem is not a firewall at all. Check documentation for your linux distro.

Comment: @ram try `service firewalld stop`

Comment: MySQL typically runs on port 3306, so add that to your firewall

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to disable my firewall to get to work as well: `sudo ufw disable`

Answer (score 10):

This happens when you forget to start the database before connecting to it:

```
mysql.server start
```

Then

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: in the terminal on mac and linux. I believe it is the same in windows CMD but I am not certain.

Comment: I had to start MySQL server using `sudo service mysqld start` in my AWS EC2 instance with MySQL Community Server.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, this problem may occur because your MySQL server is not installed and running.

To do that, start a command prompt as administrator and enter the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install
```

If you get "service successfully installed" message then you need to start the MySQL service. To do that: go to *Services* window
([Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) → *Services* → *Open Services*).
Search for MySQL and *start* it from the top navigation bar.
Then if trying to open *mysql.exe*, it will work.

Comment: A little mistake, `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin" ` and then `mysqld --install`. In addition the server number depends on the download.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the `my.cnf` file. If it contains a `[client]` section, and the `port` is other than the real listen port (default 3306), you must connect the server with an explicit parameter, `-P 3306`, e.g.

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p -P 3306
```

Comment: where can i search the `my.cnf` . its not there in wamp server, in my laptop

Comment: On windows, it calls ‘my.ini’ usually

Answer (score 2):

If you are running `Ubuntu` via WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and wish to connect to the MySQL instance on the host machine, you will need to use the host machine's IPv4 address e.g. `192.X.X.X`, not `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

```
$ mysql -u <user> -h 127.0.0.1 -p -P 3306

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
```

```
$ mysql -u <user> -h 192.X.X.X -p -P 3306

Welcome to the MySQL monitor...Server version: 8.0.26 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

To check your IPv4 address, go to `Settings` -> `Network $ Internet` -> `Properties` -> `IPv4 address`.

I got the same error configuring MySQL URI for `apache airflow` as:

```py
mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@localhost:3306/<database>

(mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111)
```

or

```py
mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:3306/<database>

(mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
```

Fixed the error configuring the URI as:

```py
mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@192.X.X.X:3306/<database>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are here with the same error message and you use [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) - try to use the name of the database service as a host.

```
services:
  app:
    blablabla
  db:
    blablabla
```

I mean, instead of:

```
127.0.0.1 or localhost
```

use:

```
db
```

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way, especially if you just want to do a sanity check or grab some data, is to use the container shell by running the following command:
`docker exec -it <container_name> sh`. Then, you can run `mysql -p` to access MySQL shell.

---

Notes:
One way for finding a container name is by running `docker ps`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the bind-address parameter to 127.0.0.1 in the MySQL configuration file (*my.ini* or *my.cnf*) or use the one that is defined there.

If that doesn't work you should check that the MySQL service is actually running.

Comment: I have add the line "bind-address = 127.0.0.1" to the file my.cnf. But it doesn't work.

Comment: If this line is present, mysql will listen ONLY to the address listed. To enable remote access, you should REMOVE this line. Be aware of the security implication this has.

Comment: adding `bind-address =127.0.0.1` in my.cnf disables remote connection to the DB. So even if it would work (which it isn't) - that's not a good solution.

Comment: The bind-address should be 0.0.0.0 unless you don't want anyone *else* to connect.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running on a non-default port, you may try using `--port=<port num>` provided `--skip-networking` is `not enabled.`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.

The following helped me fix the problem

Go to *Control Panel* → *Administrative Tools* → *Services*. Inside this you will most certainly see the MySQL service: right click and say start (force start).

Comment: On Windows, presumably?

Comment: yes @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 0):

I just have this problem... running in Windows 7 and [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) server ... after [reading this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?547573-ERROR-2003-%28HY000%29).

I found that Antivirus Firewall had caused the problem.

Comment: What is *"Antivirus Firewall"*? An actual product name?

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (redirects to the generic *https://www.sitepoint.com/community/*).

Answer (score 0):

***For [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) users*** - When trying to connect to the local SQL database server using `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p` and your database is running in a **Docker** container, make sure the MySQL service is up and running (verify using `docker ps` and also check that you are in the right port as well). If the container is down you'll get connection error.

The best practice is to set the IP addresses in `/etc/hosts` on your machine:

```
127.0.0.1 db.local
```

And running it by `mysql -u root -h db.local -p`.

If all this is ok and working (or in case it was working and sudenly it stopped), you should check if your container is not out of space. In this case MySQL isn't able to authorize and create connection. The symptom is that port is active, everything looks great, but if you try to connect, the connection is either cancelled, or refused.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is open port 3306 (more [here](https://www.hackingarticles.in/penetration-testing-on-mysql-port-3306/)):

```
nmap -p3306 127.0.0.1
```

If you receive something like:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-01-07 11:55 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000082s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```

then open port 3306:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Or `sudo ufw allow 3306` if you use [UFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall).

Check: `netstat -lnp | grep mysql` you should get something like this:

```
cp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2048/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      2048/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     514961   2048/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     514987   2048/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Try don’t shut down"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59494491/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all of the above and it still did not work. Check firewall.

I was trying to connect from a windows machine to a MySql Server 5.7.32 installed on a VirtualBox machine with CentOs7. I have tried everything and it was not working, even though i could ping the machine i couldn't connect to the MySql Server.

On CentOs7 the commands to check the firewall are:

Step 1: Check the status of your firewall service:

```
systemctl status firewallid.service
```

Step 2: Disable the firewall service

```
systemctl stop firewallid.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to connect to the MySQL server in the Docker container

I **fixed** by following the steps below.

1. Go inside the container:

```sh
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

2. Run this command:

```sh
echo "bind-address           = 0.0.0.0" >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

3. Exit from the container

```sh
exit
```

4. Restart the container

```sh
docker restart mysql
```

5. Go inside the container

```sh
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

6. Connect to the MySQL server, and enter your password

```sh
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with `Centos Linux` and `MYSQL 8.0.26`. I fixed it by opening the port from the firewall. You can run the below command if [3306] is the MySQL port and [public] is the active zone (default configuration)

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also, I looked for `bind-address=127.0.0.1` but did not configure anywhere in the configuration.`/etc/my.cnf` `/etc/my.cnf.d/*`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when connecting to RDS on AWS when the database has run out of storage capacity. You have to increase the amount of storage capacity available to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that, your password doesn't contain the '@' character. As an example, If your password is **Jane@123**, then the following error will be displayed.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '123@localhost' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
```

Answer (score -3):

I just restarted my MySQL server and the problem was solved.

On Windows, `net stop MySQL`, and then `net start MySQl`.

On [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) (Linux): `sudo service start mysql`

Answer (score -3):

I changed the installation directory on re-install, and it worked.

Answer (score -4):

Please make sure your MySQL server is running on localhost.

**On Linux**

To check if MySQL server is running:

`sudo service mysql status`

To run MySQL server:

`sudo service mysql start`

**On Windows**

To check if MySQL server is running:

`net start`

If MySQL is not in list, you have to start/run MySQL.

To run MySQL server:

`net start mysql`