# Mysql Remote Access

Tags: mysql

I am connecting a Mysql server from remote system using windows.Getting mysql server error 2003. Firewall is off. What will be the  problem?

Comment: Duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111

Comment: I tried that now... no luck so for

Answer (score 0):

If the server is running Windows, try to enable the Firewall on the server and open the port for mysql.