# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '23.23.*.*' (110)

Tags: mysql, iptables

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql server but is encountering this error.On the server I have

1. set bind-address to 0.0.0.0
2. Changed Iptables to look like this

   ```
   target     prot opt source               destination 
   DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  107.22.*.*           0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
   ```

   where 107.22.** is the IP of the machine I am trying to connect from
3. Restarted UFW
4. verified that my AWS security groups allow port 3306 is allowed access from everywhere.

What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: `DROP tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:3306`, probably should come last

Comment: similar one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `iptables` to look like this instead:

```
target     prot opt source               destination 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  107.22.*.*           0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
```

Otherwise, all 3306 traffic gets dropped by the firewall.