# MySql connection threw c++ in ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I have installed necessary packages

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev

here is my code:

```
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*

  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!

*/
#include <mysql_connection.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!'  AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:11840", "root", "n");
/* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message"); // replace with your statement
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }``
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  //cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
    // << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compiled using:

```
sudo g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/cppconn -o testapp mysql_connect1.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
```

it got compiled successfully

when I run:

```
./testapp
```

Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'...

```
# ERR: SQLException in mysql_connect1.cpp# ERR: 
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) 
(MySQL error code: 2003, SQLState: HY000 )
```

I get the above error

I made the below changes as suggested [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111):

- run the command vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- comment bind-address = 127.0.0.1 using the # symbol
- restart your mysql server once.

But it still didn't work

output of:

```
root@knils-HP:/home/knils# sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp 0 0 *:mysql *:* LISTEN 11840/mysqld
root@knils-HP:/home/knils#
```

Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your server runs on 11840 and the user account you are using is allowed to connect from localhost?

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:11840", "root", "n");
```

Your console output that more looked like a processID or internal port for me.
MySQL usually runs on 3306 except you changed that on your own.

Can you try:

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "n");
```

?