# Apache on Debian server to connect to extern mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, debian

I have servers :

- a Sql server
- a VPS

I installed apache on my debian server.
I want to access my SQL server through PDO.
But an error occurs :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_sql_server_ip' (110)'
```

However, I can access my SQL server from local apache server (MAMP).
So I think the problem is client side.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111)

Answer (score 0):

On MAMP , click File Menu > Edit Template > MySQL my.cnf

and change `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` by `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

(don't edit directly /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf because MAMP will overwrite the file on restart)

Comment: Hi, my SQL server is not local. It's an OVH private database.

Comment: So you have a private MySQL database and a VPS and you know their IP addresses ? and how did you configured MAMP when you said the connection worked ?

Comment: I just put my sql sever's ip instead of localhost when I want to connect with PDO and it works