# Cant connect to MySQL server on localhost(0).Error No.2003

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I am not able to connect to my SQLYog now. I am learning database queries.I could not view my databases.Initially, I downloaded SQLYOg Community 64, installed it and while 'connect to MySQL Host'. Then the following error has come..
  [image: Error 2003]

Before that, I went to services.msc from 'run', and stopped the 'Windows Firefall'.Still, it is not solved. I am a beginner. Let me know how to rectify it..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because you need to check with the Antivirus. I checked that in my system i was using K7 Antivirus which was blocking the new connection. Kindly check if your antivirus is blocking your connection using current settings.

Hope this is Useful.

Comment: yeah yes the error is because of the k7 antivirus installed newly

Answer (score 1):

I too was getting the same error when i try to start the mysql.
Then i did a bit of research on that and did the following,

firstly, you must login to an admin account.
then goto services.msc, search for mysql, right click and select the start.

Make sure that the port is free and it exists.
And enter the right password in your sqlyog.

this link might help you,
http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html