# Unable to connect to mySQL remotely even after creating a user

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have installed and configured mySQL with WAMP server in a separate dedicated server for our Bug tracking Application. (eg.IP of the server 10.11.1.111)

I m trying to connect to the mySQL DB remotely from my local PC, but I m not able to connect.

Getting the following error,

> `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.11.1.111'
>   (10060).`

I ve tried creating a user from the IP I am going to connect

```
grant all on *.* to 'adminuser'@'10.22.2.222' identified by
'testadmin';
```

(adminuser@10.22.2.222) and able to see the user in the user and previleges column. But still unable to connect remotely.

Comment: please check the url  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111

Comment: @UIDeveloper I tried the commentso n that link but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by  doing the following.

1. Login to mysqlworkbench with root credentials
2. Go to users and privileges
3. Create account and mention the host the user will be accessing from
4. Go to administrative role tab and select all
5. Go to schema privileges , select the privileges you want to provide.
6. Click Apply

Go to Windows firewall setting and open the mysql port.