# Can't connect to remote MySQL server Error 2003 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

Sorry but I started this thread because I couldn't found a solution.
I'm using MySQL Router and InnoDB Cluster to deploy a sandbox cluster. I've followed the documentation [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-using-router.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-sandbox-deployment.html) , but when I try to connect by `mysqlsh --uri root@localhost:6446`, it outputs this following error:

> MySQL Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to remote MySQL server for client connected to '127.0.0.1:6446'

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111 ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check the myrouter log?

In my log it shows the following:

```
Failed connecting with Metadata Server mysql-db1.mjdh.local:3308: Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql-db1.mjdh.local' (110) (2005)
```

So I write it in hosts and the problem missed.