# Unable to connect to localhost:3306 (2003) for MySQL 8.0.21 on Windows

Tags: mysql, database

I am using `MySQL workbench` to connect to my `local` server. Everything was running fine and suddenly I jumped in a connection refused errors. I tried restarting the server again and again. `Clearing temp` files and also `restarted` my machine. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111) post from which I tried a couple of things like `net stop` and stopping the process from the `services` list but in the services list it shows as below:

[image]

I waited like for 30 mins but still, the service is not stopped.
Also, below is the screenshot for MySQL workbench when I try to start the server:

[image]

Is there anything specific which I need to do in order to resolve this error:

Comment: you have to check the mysql error log, which will tell you what is wrong

Comment: Try changing the `MySQL service` to manual instead of automatic. Also see if there is a `mysql process` still running in the `Windows Task Manager` and if so, try to kill that.

Comment: "Is there anything specific which I need to do in order to resolve this error" yes, you need to Debug ...

Comment: Click on `MANAGEMENT->Server Status` Check the port number that MySQL is listening on

Comment: I checked the port number and it's 3306 which comes by default

Comment: I changed `MySQL service` to manual and refreshed but still didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @lukk that was so helpful.

Comment: Will reinstalling the MySQL do the trick?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I resolved my own problem in this way. I referred the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html#:%7E:text=The%20error%20(2003)%20Can%27,one%20configured%20on%20the%20server.) for this particular error and for my error which is of `2003` type it said that look for `mysqld.exe` process in `task manager` and if you don't find any then start the server. But, in my case I found 2 `mysqld.exe` processes running. So, I killed those processes and restarted the server. It worked!!

Might help someone someday :)